# GitBook does not copy images

Tags: gitbook

I've got a project using GitBook: https://github.com/akauppi/plantuml-book

It generates images from PlantUML source. For some reason, those images don't get copied to the GitBook's `_book` folder, and therefore don't make it into the book.

Expected:

GitBook would notice the image references, e.g.

```
![](./hello.svg)
```

..and copy such image files to the right location (in this case `_book/chapter1/hello.svg).

Actual:

```
$ tree _book/chapter1/
_book/chapter1/
└── DIAGRAMS.html
```

No images there. :(

Note: I did not make this a GitBook issue, since that project seems pretty dead ([link](https://github.com/GitbookIO/gitbook/issues/1808)).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my `.gitignore` included the generated *.svg and *.png files, and GitBook automatically ignores everything in `.gitignore`.

The solution: [these lines](https://github.com/akauppi/plantuml-book/blob/master/.bookignore#L16-L18) in `.bookignore`:

```
# Bring in the generated files (having them in .gitignore would otherwise leave them out)
!*.svg
!*.png
```